# Pygame; not being able to move to the next level

Tags: python, pygame

I'm new to pygame and this is a simple game I'm making. I've been encountering this problem where I can go up to level 2 but not further.

This is main.py:

```
import pygame
import sys
from Button import Button
from level_maps import *
from level import Level
pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_caption("My Platformer Game")
background_image = pygame.image.load("owl.png")

background_image = pygame.transform.scale(background_image, (SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
background_rect = background_image.get_rect()
font = pygame.font.Font(None, 36)

level_no = 0
game_start = False

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
screen.fill("black")
start_button = Button(SCREEN_WIDTH // 2 - 100, SCREEN_HEIGHT // 2, 200, 50, "Start Game")

level = Level(map[0], screen)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
run = True
while True:
    screen.blit(background_image, background_rect)
    start_button.draw(screen)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if start_button.rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                game_start = True


    if game_start:
        screen.fill("Black")
        level.run()
        #level_no = level.level

        if level_no == 2:
            screen.fill("black")
            level = Level(map[1], screen)
            level.run()
        level_no = level.level
        if level_no == 3:
            screen.fill("black")
            level = Level(map[2], screen)
            level.run()
        if level_no == 4:
            screen.fill("black")
            level = Level(map[3], screen)
            level.run()

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
```

My level maps are in level_maps.py which looks like this:

```py
map = [[
    '            ',
    '            ',
    '            ',
    '            ',
    '            ',
    '            ',
    '            ',
    '        KKK ',
    '            ',
    '  P KKK         ',
    '              C ',
    'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',],
    [
    'KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK',
    'B            ',
    'B            ',
    'B            ',
    'B   KKKK   KKKK      ',
    'B   B         B',
    'B   B         B ',
    'B   B    K    B',
    'B   B    B    B',
    '    B    B    B',
    'P   B    B    B',
    'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
],
[
    'KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK',
    '              ',
    '              ',
    '              ',
    '              ',
    '              ',
    '              ',
    '        KKK   ',
    '              ',
    '  P KKK         ',
    '                ',
    'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
]]
```

And also in the level.py where I have the Level class, I have a function to increment level.

```
def check_end(self):
    player = self.player_surf.sprite
    if player.rect.x > 200:
    self.level += 1
    print(self.level)
```

[This is the output to printing self.level](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDU2U.png)

Even though it prints out 3, the level map does not load, the second map loads over and over again, it does not go further. How do I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to SO! This is a lot of code, can you run us through it? For instance, what is "Level"

Comment: Level is a class which I use to place things on the map, it also has functions that handle collision and also checks the end of a level.